# A fix for a botched implementation of Ryan Fait's sticky footer?

Tags: css, sticky-footer

I originally implemented Ryan Fait's sticky footer method, and it worked fine.  Somewhere along the line when I was putting in plugins, content and changing things up, something went awry.  I've tried to fix it with no luck.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[Here](http://blog.junctionlife.com/subscribe-for-junctionlife-updates/subscription-success/) is a page from the site, while you can view the CSS [here](http://blog.junctionlife.com/wp-content/themes/jl-blog/style.css).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this source](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/layout.css), you should have `height: 100%;` on the body as well as the html tag. You have `height: 1%;` on the body.

EDIT: Sorry, you do have `height: 100%` on the body. Your `.post, .page` class style is overwriting the height on the body to `1%`.

Comment: Man, you're awesome!  I should have Firebugged that when trying to fix it!  Kudos!